# DataGridView delete row when DataSource is List<myClass>

Tags: c#, linq, datagridview, iqueryable

On my `DataGridView` I have set the *AllowUserToDeleteRows* to True.

When I set my `DataGridView`'s `DataSource` to an `IQueryable`

```
var dc = new Data.CustomersDataContext();
var q = dc.Customers;
dataGridView1.DataSource = q;
```

I can delete rows from it, but when I set it to a `List<T>`

```
var dc = new Data.CustomersDataContext();
var l = dc.Customers.ToList();
dataGridView1.DataSource = l;
```

I can no more delete rows (nothing happens when I press delete button)

How can I keep my `DataSource` as a `List<T>` and also be able to delete rows?

Comment: does Customers have list of struct or class instaces?

Comment: @Junaith I don't know. It is what Linq-to-Sql generates.

Comment: @Junaith I checked my dbml Designer, it is A list of Customer where Customer is a class derived from INotifyPropertyChanging, INotifyPropertyChanged

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because `DataGridView` allows to remove rows only when it is bond to `IBindingList` implementation (see note below), and `IBindingList.AllowRemove` returns true.

You can wrap your list into [`BindingList<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132679%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), which allows to remove items by default:

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = new BindingList<Customer>(dc.Customers.ToList());
```

**Note.** `Data.CustomersDataContext.Customers` implements [`IListSource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.ilistsource%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), which returns `IBindingList` with `AllowRemove == true`, that's why your first case works, as expected. `DGV` knows about `IListSource` and uses `IListSource.GetList()` result as the data source.