# No add new row on DataGridView

Tags: winforms, datagridview, vb.net-2010

Similar to this question [DataGridView doesn’t allow user to Delete Row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32181964/datagridview-doesn-t-allow-user-to-delete-row/32182330#32182330) I am using a binding source but I don't visually see the add new line with the * as in the screenshot of the above question. I can select a row and press the delete button and it deletes ok, just cannot add a new row interactively. What I am doing wrong?

NB: My columns are created at design time.

Code to load data is as follows:

```
Private bindingSource1 As New BindingSource
Private Sub LoadDeploymentNotes(ByVal items As List(Of DeploymentNote))
    DataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = False
    Dim column = CType(DataGridView1.Columns("ColumnChange"), DataGridViewComboBoxColumn)
    column.DataSource = [Enum].GetValues(GetType(Change))
    bindingSource1.DataSource = items
    DataGridView1.DataSource = bindingSource1
    DataGridView1.Refresh()
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Gosh needed a Constructor in my class DeloymentNote that received no arguments.